# making an audio file very play slow online

Tags: javascript, html, audio

What's the way to make an audio file play very slow with html5 and/or javascript? 
I know there is the playbackrate function, but am looking to slow play much more than 50%.. (eg a 30 mins file should slow down to play over 730 days..) 
Is there a way..? Cheers!

Comment: Are you really doing to keep your computer running and the browser open for 730 days? :O

Comment: I don't think you understand what you're asking.  There is no audio in existence with a bitrate high enough to make what you're asking even worth attempting.  Put it this way, with your example figures 1ms of the original file would last for over 35 seconds after being slowed.  Just stop and think about those figures and then decide to do whatever it is you're trying to do in a completely different way.

Comment: well.. its correct that am not intending to keep the computer on, nor is it concerned with an actual audio-ability - but scriptablity. The idea is to have something of an impossibility in time. The audio files are of events that never happen, hence the playback idea is to keep up with the impossible. However, it will be good to have the impossibility being possible in script..

Answer (score -1):

I think using [playbackrate](/questions/tagged/playbackrate) should do the trick:

```
var audio = new Audio('audiofile.mp3');
audio.playbackRate = 0.00001; // -ish, you do the math :-)
```

Comment: playbackrate can't be that slow - it simply won't work.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I was convinced I used it like this once, but I must be mistaken with something else. It doesn't even seem to take a number below 0.5 so I think my answer should be considered null and void...

Comment: yes. I thought this approach could solve it - but it seems the playbackrate does not respond to values of 0.0X.. Only 0.1/0.5/etc..